# Conectar base de datos sitio php5 a php7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy intentando pasar mi sitio a un servidor con php7 con mysqli:

Tengo un archivo conexion.php que he modificado y ahora tiene el siguiente aspecto:

```
<?php

$hostname_conexion = "localhost";
$database_conexion = "opentach";
$username_conexion = "root";
$password_conexion = "";

# $conexion = mysql_connect($hostname_conexion, $username_conexion, $password_conexion) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'opentach');


?>
```

Solo he comentado la linea de mysql_connect y he incorporado la de mysqli

Al cargar me da el siguiente error, que significa?:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in /var/www/html/opentach/index.php on line 84
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
>   in /var/www/html/opentach/index.php on line 86
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /var/www/html/opentach/index.php on line 86

las líneas del index al que hacen referencia son:

```
mysqli_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$query_datos_meta = "SELECT * FROM configuracion WHERE idioma = '".$_SESSION['idioma']."'";
$datos_meta = mysqli_query($query_datos_meta, $conexion) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_datos_meta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos_meta);
$totalRows_datos_meta = mysqli_num_rows($datos_meta);
```

Está modificado, lo único que he hecho es cambiar `mysql` por `mysqli`.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar solo el código donde recibes los errores, incluyendo las variables relacionadas al mismo y o sus valores?

Comment: Las tres advertencias que muestras indican que debes migrar todo tu código, **no solamente la conexión** al estilo `mysqli`. Para verificar cómo se realizan los aspectos más importantes de `mysqli` puedes ver los ejemplos del Manual de PHP: [conexiones](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), [ejecutar consultas](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php), [sentencias preparadas](https://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Siempre aparecen dos tipos de ejemplos: *orientado a objetos*, y *por procedimientos*, recomendaría el 1º.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo de la siguiente manera las conexiones que pase de PHP5 a PHP7. Intente modificar lo menos posible porque tenía muchas consultas que modificar.

**Conexión**

```
$link = mysqli_connect('servidor', 'mi_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_bd');
```

**Query**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Opciones';
```

**Consultar**

```
$result = $link->query($query);
```

**Imprimir**

```
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$line["id"]."</td></tr>";
}
```